# Use RelayCommand with not only buttons

Tags: xaml, mvvm, windows-8.1, mvvm-light

I am using MVVM Light in my project and I am wondering if there is any way to use RelayCommand with all controls (ListView or Grid, for example).

Here is my current code:

```
private void Item_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var currentItem = (TechItem)GridControl.SelectedItem;
    if(currentItem != null)
        Frame.Navigate(typeof(TechItem), currentItem);
}
```

I want to move this code to Model and use RelayCommand, but the ListView, Grid and other controls don't have `Command` and `CommandParameter` attributes.

What does MVVM Light offer to do in such cases?

Comment: You can use `Interaction.Behaviors` to bind event to Command [How to add Command Behavior in windows store 8.1 MVVM application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23467911/how-to-add-command-behavior-in-windows-store-8-1-mvvm-application)

Comment: Could you make the item template a button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following on from the link har07 posted this might be of some use to you as I see you mention `CommandParameter`.

It is possible to send the "Tapped" item in the list to the relay command as a parameter using a custom converter.

```
<ListView
    x:Name="MyListView"
    ItemsSource="{Binding MyCollection}"
    ItemTemplate="{StaticResource MyTemplate}"
    IsItemClickEnabled="True">

    <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="ItemClick">
             <core:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding ViewInMoreDetail}" InputConverter="{StaticResource TapConverter}" />
        </core:EventTriggerBehavior>
    </i:Interaction.Behaviors>

</ListView>
```

Custom converter class

```
public class TapConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        var args = value as ItemClickEventArgs;

        if (args != null)
            return args.ClickedItem;

        return null;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

In your view model you then have a `relaycommand`.

```
public RelayCommand<MyObject> MyRelayCommand
{
    get;
    private set;
}
```

In your constructor initialise the relay command and the method you want to fire when a tap happens.

```
MyRelayCommand = new RelayCommand<MyObject>(HandleTap);
```

This method receives the object that has been tapped in the listview as a parameter.

```
private void HandleTap(MyObject obj)
{
    // obj is the object that was tapped in the listview.   
}
```

Don't forget to add the TapConverter to your App.xaml

```
<MyConverters:TapConverter x:Key="TapConverter" />
```